# Filling QGraphicsScene with items in thread

Tags: multithreading, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have the thread where the worker object is running infinite cycle. Here I have the following code that I would like it to read coordinates from list and place QGraphicsEllipseItem on these coordinates. The list can be updated by another thread, so I protect it by mutex. But sometimes the size of list may grow up so I would like to create new QGraphicsEllipse items for it if needed.

```
int meter_to_pixel_ratio = 20;
int x_pixel, y_pixel;
int i;

forever {

    visualizationDataMutex->lock();

    while(ellipseList->count()<visualizationData->count())
    {
        qDebug() << "Creating new visual item...";
        ellipseList->append(new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0));
        ellipseList->last()->setVisible(false);
        visualizationScene->addItem(ellipseList->last());
    }

    for(i=0; i<visualizationData->count(); i++)
    {
        x_pixel = meter_to_pixel_ratio*visualizationData->at(i)->x();
        y_pixel = meter_to_pixel_ratio*visualizationData->at(i)->y();

        ellipseList->at(i)->setPos(x_pixel, y_pixel);
        ellipseList->at(i)->setBrush(QBrush(*visualizationColor->at(i)));

        if(!ellipseList->at(i)->isVisible()) ellipseList->at(i)->setVisible(true);
    }

    visualizationDataMutex->unlock();

    // repaint scene
    visualizationScene->update();

    QThread::msleep(100);
}
```

The problem I have is, that when I try to run the program I´ll obtain a runtime error. Tried to *qDebug()* the *ellipseList->count()* and seems to have the exactly same number of elements as needed (as *visualizationData->count()*). When commented these three lines:

```
        //ellipseList->at(i)->setPos(x_pixel, y_pixel);
        //ellipseList->at(i)->setBrush(QBrush(*visualizationColor->at(i)));

        //if(!ellipseList->at(i)->isVisible()) ellipseList->at(i)->setVisible(true);
```

program can run without crashing. I do not understand why is this happening since there is no other function working with QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene. (QGraphicsView was added from Qt Designer environment into mainwindow).

Comment: But there is another function working with the QGraphicsView and the GraphicsScene, it's the code inside Qt's event loop that renders the window, handles input events, etc.  That's why Qt has this rule:  "Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread."  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I migrated all my code into mainwindow object and pasted it into slot that is now periodically started by QTimer signals and seems to run OK now.